# $.get is not successful from controller

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a javascript as follows

```
$('#MessageContent').replaceWith("Hi there"); //just sets value to Hi There

    $('body').delegate('#MessageDesc', 'change', function () {
        var sMessageTypeID = $("#MessageDesc").val();
        $.get('@Url.Action("GetMessageContent")', { MessageTypeID: sMessageTypeID }, function (data) {
            $('#MessageContent').replaceWith(data); //should replace hi there with a value
        });
    });
```

It should replace the content in the textbox called "MessageContent" with what is being returned.

My Controller Action looks like this

```
public ActionResult GetMessageContent(long MessageTypeID)
    {
        tblMessageType tblMessageType = db.tblMessageTypes.Single(t => t.MessageTypeID == MessageTypeID);
        return View(tblMessageType.MessageContent);
    }
```

I have verified that the value in tblMessageType.MessageConent looks good! I'm pretty sure the problem is in the Controller, not the JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, be sure your controller action is being called, then try returning a simple `JsonResult` instead.

Something like this:

```
public JsonResult GetMessageContent(long MessageTypeID)
{
    tblMessageType tblMessageType = db.tblMessageTypes.Single(t => t.MessageTypeID == MessageTypeID);

    return Json(tblMessageType.MessageContent, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Try replacing this line:

```
$('#MessageContent').replaceWith(data);
```

with this one:

```
$('#MessageContent').text(data);
```

or

```
$('#MessageContent').val(data);
```

Comment: You can absolutely return a view.  I do that all the time.

Comment: same result...just skips this line of code as if $.get is unsuccessful

Comment: Sorry...this line of code... $('#MessageContent').replaceWith(data); //should replace hi there with a value

Comment: Is your action method being called? Do you see any JavaScript error using Firebug for example?

Comment: yes, it is hitting the action method successfully. When I hover over this in the controller "tblMessageType.MessageContent" it shows the correct value from the DB

Comment: ok well now at least I can tell that the value in data (in the following line) $('#MessageContent').text(data); is correct - just not replacing the text yet

Comment: Try `$('#MessageContent').val(data);`

Comment: Try disabling your browser cache when changing JavaScript or press Ctrl+F5 to force a full refresh.

Comment: ok it actually works if I take out this line $('#MessageContent').replaceWith("Hi there"); For some reason that seems to replace the textbox with a label or something.  Thank you all!

Comment: Yes... nice catch. It's inserting HTML content. That's what `replaceWith` actually does. http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough information in your post to provide a conclusive answer, but try the following:

- Make sure there are no JavaScript errors (e.g. in IE9, use the Script tab of the F12 tools)
- Look at the HTTP traffic (again in IE9, you can use the F12 tools).  See what HTTP status you get back.  200=OK, 404=Not Found, 401=Unauthorized, 500=Error
- Set a breakpoint in your controller action.
- Make sure the action is being called.
- Make sure the parameter to the action is correctly populated.
- Make sure no exceptions are thrown in the controller.
- Make sure the view doesn't return "Hi there"  ;-)

Comment: Thank you, I have verified all of the above.